# Shell script read a file line by line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting. I need to read a file that works in all shells that has variables defined in it. Something like:

```
variable1=test1
variable2=test2
    ....
```

I have to read this file line by line and prepare new string separated by spaces, like:

```
variable=variable1=test1 variable2=test2 ....
```

I tried with the below code:

```
while read LINE
do
$VAR="$VAR $LINE"
done < test.dat
```

but it's throwing me this error:

```
command not found Test.sh: line 3: = variable1=test1
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your script is the leading `$` before `var` is initialized, try:

```
#/bin/bash

while read line; do 
    var="$var $line"
done < file

echo "$var"
```

However you can do this with the `tr` command by substituting the newline character with a space.

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' < file
variable1=test1 variable2=test2

$ var="$(tr '\n' ' ' < file)"

$ echo "$var"
variable1=test1 variable2=test2
```

Answer (score 4):

When defining a shell variable you must omit the $. So `VAR="bla"` is right, `$VAR="bla"` is wrong. The $ is only necessary for using the variable, as in `echo $VAR`;

```
while read LINE
do
  VAR="$VAR $LINE"
done < test.dat
```